# JQuery's load() not loading page on first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Pls see my test page: http://oneniceday.com/SR-1/Test1.html
(I cannot use codepen.io or other online editors as this is about AJAX and it cannot load the pages from an external host/domain).

Here's how to reproduce the bug:

1) Go to above link

2) Click once in the blank area anywhere

3) All you see is nothing on the screen (perhaps some scrollbars)
The correct behaviour should be "Test2.html" gets loaded but nothing happens

4) Click again. Now "Test2.html" gets loaded properly.

Why is it the first time on click, JQuery's load() doesn't work properly?

Tks!

Comment: do you have any specific code regarding this issue? you can post it down at your post, that would be great if you add those `.load()` code in it.

Comment: You will have some console errors for sure here.. One of them I got is `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).revolution is not a function`

Comment: You are an error on your jquery when you click on the blank area

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**.

Comment: move the plugin revolution files to load in the parent page and not in the one loaded by ajax. This will fix the error you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use some JQuery plugin 'revolution', but didn't include it. So JQuery object doesn't have `revolution` method.

Solution: `revolution` plugin must be included before your script will try to apply slider.

Comment: the plugin is loaded in the page called by ajax. But it should be in the parent page so that is already available on page load

Comment: @Lelio : Tks, IT WORKS NOW!!!